# 1588 clock synchronization

Tags: clock

In my new design i have a clock generator which give 25MHZ, 125MHZ, 100MHZ for different peripherals including the processor. I need to implement 1588 synchronization. I can calculate the delay in the internal clock and the external clock(from ethernet packets) by the processor. I need to design something so that i can give a clock correction to the internal clock. Please suggest a way.

Thanks

Comment: Write an IEEE-1588 clock servo algorithm. Or 'borrow' an existing one. A search engine may be of help.

Comment: Is there any hardware solution for this. Thanks